# c++ type alias not working when testing specialization

Tags: c++, templates, specialization, type-alias

Using C++, trying to implement: is_specialization_of

```
template<typename T, template<typename...> class Template>
struct is_specialization_of : std::false_type {};

template<template<typename...> class Template, typename... Tn>
struct is_specialization_of<Template<Tn...>, Template> : std::true_type {};

template<typename... Tn>
struct tstruct {};

template<typename... Tn>
using ustruct = tstruct<Tn...>;

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    printf( "test u<int> against u, return %s\n", is_specialization_of<ustruct<int>, ustruct>::value ? "true" : "false" );
    printf( "test u<int> against t, return %s\n", is_specialization_of<ustruct<int>, tstruct>::value ? "true" : "false" );
    printf( "test t<int> against u return %s\n", is_specialization_of<tstruct<int>, ustruct>::value ? "true" : "false" );
    printf( "test t<int> against t, return %s\n", is_specialization_of<tstruct<int>, tstruct>::value ? "true" : "false" );
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Return:

```
test u<int> against u, return false
test u<int> against t, return true
test t<int> against u return false
test t<int> against t, return true
```

Looks like the type alias is not considered exactly as the original type

I am using Visual Studio Community 2017

> Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.15.26732.1 for x64

However when trying to compile the same code using gcc, it returns:

```
test u<int> against u, return true
test u<int> against t, return true
test t<int> against u return true
test t<int> against t, return true
```

Is there anything I can do for a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Looks like the type alias is not considered exactly as the original type, or did I miss something?

The alias specialization is *exactly* the type it stands for. But the alias *tempalte* is an entirely **distinct template**. The reason for your output is specified by [temp.alias]

> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.alias#1) A template-declaration in which the declaration is an
>   alias-declaration declares the identifier to be an alias template. An
>   alias template is a name for a family of types. The name of the alias
>   template is a template-name.
>
> [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.alias#2) When a template-id refers to the specialization of an alias
>   template, it is equivalent to the associated type obtained by
>   substitution of its template-arguments for the template-parameters in
>   the type-id of the alias template.

If we examine your test cases with the above two paragraphs in mind, we see that:

1. *"test `u<int>` against `u`"* - `ustruct<int>` is equivalent to specifying `tstruct<int>` directly. And `tstruct<int>` is not a specialization of `ustruct`. The trait needs to evaluate to false.
2. *"`test u<int>` against `t`"* - Here `ustruct<int>` is again equivalent to specifying `tstruct<int>` directly. And `tstruct<int>` is a specialization of `tstruct`. The trait should report true.
3. *"test `t<int>` against `u`"* - `tstruct<int>` is not a specialization of `ustruct`, like we observed previously. The trait should report false.
4. *"test `t<int>` against `t`"* - Should report true.

All your tests, when run in MSVC, conform to what the C++ standard says they should do. GCC is not conforming here, it's a compiler bug.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

So if we follow the standard, the expected behavior should be:

**"u<int> equivalent to t<int>"**

**BUT**

**"u is NOT equivalent to t"** or **"u and t can not be compared if they are not complete types"**

Comment: @drvkize - `ustruct` and `tstruct` aren't types, they are templates. And you can compare them, they should not be the same in a conforming compiler. like Clang for instance http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03321a93d172a609 .